# How do I retrieve a google user id securely via php?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I'm trying to set up a system that a user could sign up through google sign-in and I need a detail about a user that will always be constant. I figured that would be the ID, but that's pretty much the only detail I can't get through PHP.

I can get the details about a user using a token ID and it would return this.

```
"iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
 "sub": "110169484474386276334",
 "azp": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "aud": "1008719970978-hb24n2dstb40o45d4feuo2ukqmcc6381.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "iat": "1433978353",
 "exp": "1433981953",

 // These seven fields are only included when the user has granted the "profile" and
 // "email" OAuth scopes to the application.
 "email": "testuser@gmail.com",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "name" : "Test User",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-kYgzyAWpZzJ/ABCDEFGHI/AAAJKLMNOP/tIXL9Ir44LE/s99-c/photo.jpg",
 "given_name": "Test",
 "family_name": "User",
 "locale": "en"
```

But I can't find a detail that would be unique and constant so I can see if their account already exists. Is there something else I could use or can I retrieve the ID of a user through php?

Comment: The email must be unique for a Google account ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the labels above or where you got them, but looking at the values (and comparing them to my own collection of Gmail User IDs from Oauth), the `sub` value is the user ID field.

Counterintuitively, email is not unique, as in one account can have several email aliases, and you can change email addresses on an account.